# populate text area as you are typing in the info to the input fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to get values from a couple of inputs and pass them on to a text area outside the form without submitting the form at all, this is taking place on the same page. I'm using javascript to do this since I want the text area to populate as you are typing in the info to the inputs, since ill be using that text area as an address to then mark it on a map. below is part of the code needed to pass on the value of address to the text area, since I'm not a javascript guy im asking for help on the next part of code to display the value in the text area.

```
function getaddress() {
var direccion = document.getElementsByName("direccion").value;
var colonia = document.getElementsByName("colonia").value;
var ciudad = document.getElementsByName("ciudad").value;
var estado = document.getElementsByName("estado").value;
var pais = "Mexico";
var zip = document.getElementsByName("zip").value;
var address = direccion, colonia, ciudad, estado, pais, zip;
}
```

once the text area is filled with the values from the above function, I can then ad the ID address to get the text from it and display the marker on the map. the code for the map is below

```
function codeAddress() {

var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     draggable: false,
     position: results[0].geometry.location
});
```

many thanks in advance to all you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my way of thinking, the simplest way to update the address field is to handle the [keyup event](https://developer-dev.allizom.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onkeyup) on the form that contains the input elements in question:

```
function getaddress() {
    var direccion = document.getElementById("direccion").value;
    var colonia = document.getElementById("colonia").value;
    var ciudad = document.getElementById("ciudad").value;
    var estado = document.getElementById("estado").value;
    var pais = "Mexico";
    var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
    document.getElementById("address").value =
          direccion + " " + colonia + " " + ciudad + "\n" +
          estado + " " + pais + " " + zip;
};

document.getElementById("addressForm").onkeyup = getaddress;
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/P9ErU/

Keyup events "bubble up" from the input where the user was typing to their containing element (and eventually all the way to the document), so you don't need to handle each input individually, especially when in this case you want to do the same thing no matter which input the user is typing in.

I started with the code you posted and made the following changes:

- Give the inputs an id and use `document.getElementById()` rather than `getElementsByName()` - the latter is intended to return (potentially) many elements (hence the plural "elements" in its name) and isn't really appropriate for what you're doing.
- Use the `+` operator (not `,`) to concatenate the values together. Put some space and/or newline characters in too as shown in my code if appropriate (easy enough to remove that part if not appropriate).
- Put the resulting text into the textarea.
- I assumed the form had an id `"addressForm"`, but obviously you can change that as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I see what your doing and its really easy to follow specially the way to explain the code. the only problem is I dont know  nor can figure out how to have it print out on the text area once its inputed to the fields with out having to submit the form.

Comment: thanks I see what you did in jsfiddle ant thats what im looking for thanks

Comment: ok so I see it working on JsFiddle but I cant get it to work on DW on the test server, I plugged in both codes the one posted here and the one on JsFiddle and non of them seem to pass the variables to the text area

Comment: Does your html have matching `id` attributes set up as shown in the fiddle, including on the form? Do you have the code above in a script block that appears _after_ the form, or in an `onload` handler as shown in the fiddle?

Comment: I created a new blank doc where I copy and pasted your code just the way you have it on fiddle so I can then at the id's to mine below is your code on my test doc and to answer your ?'s the doc is onload and the script is between the 'head' tags of the doc I also tried it after the form using '<script>' block but no joy

Comment: ok I found the problem, its not your script it works great! the issue im having is my body tag <code><body onload="initialize()"></code> thats for the map to display; with out that no map, now your code is conflicting with this tag if I remove it it works perfectly, is there a way around to load your code with out being <code>window.onload = function()</code> so it wont conflict?

Comment: Remove the `onload="initialize()"` attribute from the body, and instead call `initialise()` from within the `window.onload` function. Or vice versa: add the code shown in my answer (without `window.onload`) to your existing `initialize()` function.

Comment: Hi nnnnnn well I tried removing the onload="initialize()" on the body tag and group together that function with the window.onload block you provided and I'm able to pass all variables to the text area but when I press the geocode button nothing happens the maps is displayed at all times so I know its just a JS issue now I've attached the link to fiddle where you can see all block of code for js hopping you can spot the problem, help me with it and briefly explain what was wrong.  [link]http://jsfiddle.net/ahsesino/F2bnw/

Answer (score 3):

vfor live transfer use keyup event:

```
document.getElementById('x').keyup(function(){
    document.getElementById('y').value = this.value;
});
```

or even easier with jquery:

```
$('#x').bind('keyup', function(){
    $('#y').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the non-jQuery version be `.keyup = function() {...}`? (Also,  no `#` in the element id.) Also, `.value` and `.val()` rather than `.innerHTML` and `.text()` since OP is dealing with inputs and a textarea.

Comment: thanks for edits, i got a little hasty.
i prefer .bind for jquery method to make unbinding events easier.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I was talking about `.keyup = ` for the first example, not the jQuery version - in plain JS you need to assign the property, not call it as a function. (But since you mention unbinding events in jQuery, note that `.unbind()` works on handlers bound with jQuery's shortcut `.keyup()`, `.click()`, etc.)

Comment: hi guys thanks for the reply, so if I add the first part of code that @Justin Gingy Mcdonald wrote below each var should display what the user is typing in the inputs right? then give the text area a separate id so the geocode button fetches the result and codes the address

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend processing the data at every key pressed because of the lagging that will occur in the geocode function. You will be sending multiple geocode requests while a user is typing. Likely some request won't be sent while others are being processed which will have you end up with geocoding half an address. If it does work the marker will be jumping around on the map as the user has only entered a part of the address.

My advice is to put a button the user can click when he's ready filling in the fields.

Bare in mind that you can only call the geocode function 2500 times a day as a free user.

Comment: From experience i can safely say that keyup events on only 5 elements is not bad. I myself have a page where a potential 1000+ keyups can happen. The only reason i see lag even then is because the DOM is so big to search through.

Comment: @Mic1780 - The number of elements doesn't matter - only one will be receiving keyups at a time. The lag Jeroen mentioned isn't in the keyup processing, it's in trying to use `geocode()` from within the keyup - though I'm not sure that the OP means to do that, I think they just want to populate the textarea and something else will kick off the `geocode()`.

Comment: If a keyup is being fired while the previous is still being processed you will miss it.

Comment: yes ther is a button to geocode the address once you finish typing in that part of the form its a:    <input type="button" onclick="codeAdress"> but I need th part of the code that goes in between both segments I posted to do that. thanks